# What is the minimum value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ $\forall a_n >0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=A$?

Tags: summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I don't think Lagrangian multiplier method can be used with infinite sums. I suspect this could be solved via cauchy-schwarz inequality, but I am not able to think through.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{A}{N}\right)^2 = \frac{A^2}{N}$ What happens when $N$ becomes large?

Comment: Just an additional to Achille’s: $a_n=0, n>N$

Comment: @achillehui boonhet Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) $M_2\ge M_1$ we have that

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum a_i^2}{n}}\ge \frac{\sum a_i}{n}=\frac A n \iff \sum a_i^2\ge \frac{A^2}n$$

and equality holds for $a_1=\ldots=a_n=\frac A n$.

Therefore in the limit the minimum value tends to $0$ but since

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2 =0 \implies \forall i \quad a_i =0 $$

according to the given condition the value is not reached and we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i^2 >0$$

Comment: Since I'm obviously bad at this, can you say what $n$ is, what the maximum is and when is it attained? As far as I can see the answer should be $0$ when you take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Still, (+1) though

Comment: @asdf $n$ here is the number of $a_i$ elements. For any n the minimum $A^2/n$ is atrained for $a_i=A/n$ and in the limit the minimum value tends to 0.

Comment: @gimusi The question is about infinite sums. I don't see an answer to the question here. The answer by Robert Z seems to be right one for this question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know that, I’ve solely suggested a way to show that the minimum for any $n$ is $A^2/n$ attained at $a_i=A/n$ and from here the result follows.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've edited according to your suggestion with some more explanation. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi The answer is now clear and I have given you an upvote.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks again for your constructive and kind suggestion! Regards

Answer (score 3):

Starting from achille hui's comment, for $N\geq 2$ and $n\geq 1$, take 
$$a_n:=\frac{A}{N}\cdot \begin{cases}
1-\frac{1}{N}&\text{if $n=1,\dots,N,$}\\
\frac{1}{2^{n-N}}&\text{if $n\geq N+1.$}
\end{cases}$$
Then it is easy to verify that $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq 1$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=A$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2=\frac{A^2}{N^2}\left(N\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
which goes to zero as $N$ goes to infinity. Hence the desired infimum is zero (which is not attained since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2=0$ implies that $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 1$).